# Radical axis generalization

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I’ll denote power of point $X$ respect circle $\omega$ by $\mathcal{P}_{\omega}(X)$.

Radical axis of circles $\omega_1, \omega_2$ is locus of points satisfying the following condition:
$$\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(X)= \mathcal{P}_{\omega_2}(X)$$

I know that for $k\in\mathbb{R}$, locus of points satisfying $$\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(X)=k\cdot \mathcal{P}_{\omega_2}(X)$$ is line or circle. Let this circle be $\omega_0$. And I proved that circles $\omega_0, \omega_1, \omega_2$ are coaxial.

Is there any name of circle $\omega_0$? And any materials related to this? I really want to learn about this.

Comment: https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2015-05/article_1_lema_coaxalitate.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is in part a reference request, I'd recommend the paper [Pfiefer and van Hook, *Circles, Vectors, and Linear Algebra*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691113).

(In the following I'm going to abuse notation and switch freely between $\omega, c, c(x,y),$ and $c(x,y)=0$ as ways of designating circles.)

This paper treats circles $c$ via their equations $c(x,y)=0$, where
$$
c(x,y)=\alpha(x^2+y^2)-2\beta x^2-2\gamma x^2+\delta.
$$

and views them through the lens of linear algebra (vectors, dot products, linear combinations, etc).

How does this relate to the power of a point $\mathcal{P}_{\omega}(X)?$

It turns out that  $\mathcal{P}_{c}((x,y))=c(x,y).$  In other words, the power of point $(x,y)$ wrt to the circle $c(x,y)=0$ is $c(x,y)$.

So the circle corresponding to the locus of points satisfying

$$
\mathcal{P}_{\omega_1}(X)=k\cdot \mathcal{P}_{\omega_2}(X)
$$

is the circle

$$
c_0(x,y)=c_1(x,y)-k\cdot c_2(x,y)=0.
$$

In general, the circles $c_0$ don't have a name.  But you've already spotted the special case $k=1$, which gives the radical axis.  And if $r_1,r_2$ are the circle radii, then $k=\pm r_1/r_2$ give the circles of antisimilitude, which invert $c_1$ to $c_2$ and vice versa (see pgs 78,79 of the referenced article).